# Android: Custom selectable ListView item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I've been searching for a solution to this issue for a few days now.

I'm trying to create a custom ListView list item that can be selectable for mass editing. This would be something similar to the Gmail application that lists the email in your inbox and allows you to select a set of them for an action (delete, move, etc.).

My requirements are:

- Must have a customized look. The android.R.layout.simple_list_item_[checked|multiple_choice] layouts are not suited to what i'm looking for
- I would like it to work with the given ListView#setChoiceMode and ListView#getCheckedItemPositions. Neither is the CheckedTextView. (An alternative approach to this would be fine)
- I would like to make the checkboxes appear when user selects an "edit mode"
- I would like to modify the menu options available similar to [Android's Selection Mode](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List15.html)

I've tried to add my own checkbox to my view and set an OnClickListener for it to mark the list items as selected/unselected, but that is not quite working for me.

Any help is appreciated; even if it only gets me 90% of the way there.

Please keep in mind that I'm trying to get this to work on Android versions 2.1 and up.

Thank you

Comment: I ended up answering my own question after browsing the android source code to figure out that the ListView tracks its own checked item state and a checkbox is not necessary. I'll mark it as answered when I'm allowed to. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I believe I have resolved the main problem I was facing.

I believe the problem I was having was that my view was not representing the state of the ListView. In lamens; I thought a checkbox was needed to set whether a list item was checked or not (this is the web developer in me). However, the ListView maintains its own state of whats checked and whats not, regardless if you have a view (CheckBox) to represent that or not.

layout/list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

menu/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_menu_item"
        android:title="KAMEHAMEHA!!!!!"/>

</menu>
```

menu/edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/commit_menu_item"
        android:title="Commit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cancel_menu_item"
        android:title="Cancel"/>

</menu>
```

ListViewTestActivity.java

```
package com.loesak.listviewtest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewTestActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };

    private ListView listView = null;
    private MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = null;
    private boolean editMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.listView = getListView();
        this.myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, GENRES);
        this.setListAdapter(this.myArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();

        MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();

        if(!this.editMode) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        } else {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.edit_menu_item) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "entering edit mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            this.editMode = true;
            this.listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            this.listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            this.myArrayAdapter.setEditMode(editMode);
        } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.commit_menu_item 
                || item.getItemId() == R.id.cancel_menu_item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.commit_menu_item) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "committing changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "leaving edit mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            this.editMode = false;
            this.listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
            this.listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            this.listView.clearChoices();

            this.myArrayAdapter.setEditMode(editMode);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(!this.editMode) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "list item selected at position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String str = "";
            SparseBooleanArray wtfit = l.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i = 0; i < GENRES.length; i++) {
                if(wtfit.get(i)) {
                    str += i + ", ";
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected item positions: " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private Context context;
        private String[] entires;

        private boolean editMode = false;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] entries) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, entries);

            this.context = context;
            this.entires = entries;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(view == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.text1.setText(this.entires[position] + "_1");
            viewHolder.text2.setText(this.entires[position] + "_2");
            viewHolder.checkbox1.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));

            if(this.editMode) {
                viewHolder.checkbox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.checkbox1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setEditMode(boolean editMode) {
            this.editMode = editMode;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
            CheckBox checkbox1;
        }
    }
}
```

To have the checkbox reflect the actual selected mode of the list item:

```
viewHolder.checkbox1.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));
```

That's it. Kind of obvious once you know how it all works. Too bad it took me this long to figure out. Sometimes I feel the android programming is a bit too complex at times.

The only problem I have now is that the ListView items are always redrawn when a list item is clicked. This is wreaking havoc on my list items which contain asynchronously loaded images from file. Hopefully when I beef up the performance on that portion of my code, this will disappear.

Comment: followed your instruction,still get *zero* item by calling `getCheckedItemPositions`.

Comment: @zionpi this is two year old answer for an earlier version of android, so it's probably not valid to the version of android that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this link](http://nickcharlton.net/post/building-custom-android-listviews)

This is the resource I ve read to implement my own custom list view. It was really helpful for me. I think you need to add a checkbox in the list_item.xml file and change the layout attributes.

You should also need to add a listener to the CheckBox object onCheckedChanged inside custom adapter.

Here is a sample code of mine for a custom adapter;

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {

private Activity context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Entry> entries;

public EntryAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Entry> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.entry_item, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.entries = objects;
}

public View getView (int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View viewRow = convertView;
    if(viewRow == null)
    {                   
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
        viewRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_item , null, true);                       
    }

    Entry e = entries.get(position);
    if(e != null)
    {
        TextView aka = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.authorTextView);
        TextView content = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.entryContentTextView);

        if(aka != null && content != null){

            aka.setText(e.getAka());
            content.setText(e.getContent());
        }

    }


    return viewRow;

}
```

}

In this code, there is no event listeners. What you should firstly do is to add is define an arraylist of boolean like

```
ArrayList<boolean> selectedItems;
```

after that, inside the getView method you should add the following;

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxId);
```

after that, you should add onCheckStateChanged listener inside the getView() method

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
          // find out the item is selected or not and add to selected arraylist by using the position of the element
        }

}
});
```

and lastly, you should have getSelectedMethod that returns the arraylist of selected items with respect to their positions.

Hope I understand the question and it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you @arascanakin for your answer. I apologize if I did not clearly state the problem I am having. My issue is not with creating a custom list view. In fact, I have already don't that (multi-line text, images, checkbox, etc.). My problem is with adding a checkbox and working with ListView's already built in multi-selection mode. Adding a checkbox is not enough to let the ListView know that a particular item has been selected.

Comment: @loesak I ve updated my previous answer. I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: @arascanakin this is still not quite right. I figured out the solution to my own question, and I'd love to share it with everyone, but because I'm a stackoverflow newb, I cannot post it for another 3 hours.

Comment: @arascanakin, i've posted my answer. this is what i was looking for. thank you for your help though. It did push me to keep looking.

Comment: I cannot get anything when using getCheckedItemPositions ,so set a listener to the checkbox helps a lot!Thank you!

Comment: This answer is relatively old. Use `BaseAdapter` as the parent class instead of `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

As in a previous post of mine:

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

This is the starting point for what you need. Each row must be clearly defined as you're building your views. When a specific view is clicked, you handle that specific row. One thing you could do is upon the clicking of the edit button, you'd take all the data in that row and covert it to another view that appears to be editable. Then on the confirmation, you'd update that row and convert it back to the original view.